# CUE: define a "key-value"/hashmap/"associative array"-like structure

Tags: cuelang

When defining e.g. an API, you mostly deal with objects which have a given set of (sometimes optional) keys. E.g.

```
{
    "countryCode": "ITA",
    "countryName": "Italy"
}
```

But how do you define an object with keys that can be arbitrary (optionally having certain restrictions)? E.g.

```
{
    "ITA": "Italy",
    "FRA": "France"
}
```

This is not immediately apparent from the available documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Cue, you can use a "Template" to achieve this. The official documentation for templates is hidden at the very end of the "Types and Values" tutorial, and doesn't really make it obvious that templates can be used to define "maps": https://cuelang.org/docs/tutorials/tour/types/templates/. I actually stumbled over them in another tutorial (after lots of unsuccessful searching): https://cuetorials.com/first-steps/validate-configuration/#schema-v2.

For example, this is a very loose definition of the "map" given above:

```
#countries: [string]: string
```

You can also make it more strict by specifying additional constraints for the keys or for the values:

```
#countries: [=~"^[A-Z]{3}$"]: string
```

Comment: Example from the 1st link makes sense to me. But the 2nd example "labels: [string]: string is called a “Template” in Cue and defines labels as a struct with string fields with string values. You could define the value to be something more complex." I can't really understand how from "#countries: [string]: string"  we get a struct?!

Comment: Ok, seems it's called "Pattern Constraint" https://cuelang.org/docs/references/spec/#pattern-and-default-constraints